# How can I run Windows 10's bash for Emacs mingw32 for Windows?

Tags: bash, shell, emacs, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to use the recent bash shell of Windows 10 in shell mode of Emacs (mingw32) for Windows. Could anyone advise how could I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by integration? What do you want to run from where? Keep in mind that bash shell is not a shell in itself - it's a front end to the complete Linux emulation environment (Windows Services for Linux,) while mingw32 is a native Win32 application. So any straightforward integration is hardly possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the other terminal mode: `term` or `ansi-term` by typing `M-x term` or `M-x ansi-term`.

When being invoked, these terminals will ask for the path to your shell. Here you just need to put the correct path to the Windows shell.